# Unions having privileged access to future job role changes

Tags: united-kingdom, unions

I work for a company in the UK and around 50% of the employees are a part of a union. The union has two representatives which work for the company.

Is it normal practice to allow union representatives to view future job role changes before they are given out to all staff?

Comment: And additionally, they usually have a duty of secrecy with the data they are provided.

Comment: So this is normal behaviour then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely normal for a UK workplace with a decent union representation (over 30% is decent). The union reps will be able to advise on how the changes would likely be received by the workforce.

It is easier to discuss this with a couple of reps than individually with the whole staff.

Comment: Also easier to consult the union ahead of time rather than deal with backlash from them if they feel anything is unfair.